# How did classical Chinese philosophers practice philosophy?

Tags: chinese-philosophy

Practicing Philosophy minimally requires thinking but how did classical Chinese philosophers practice philosophy ? In what way does their practice ressembles and comes appart from that of other philosophical traditions such as the Indian tradition ?

I pieced together a list of plausible candidates but was unable to find any targeted authoritative answer: teacher to student dialogues; study and reflection on classical texts; revision and application of ideas based on practice; and moral reflection on personal and political practice.

(I extended my post with examples as I didn't feel that my question had been well understood)

Comment: You might find this answer relevant: 'Why is Confucianism considered a brilliant philosophical school of thought?' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/86757/why-is-confucianism-considered-a-brilliant-philosophical-school-of-thought/86768#86768 Confucius very much has the founding role for Chinese philisophy, like Socrates for Western philosophy.

Comment: Some others: 'Western Empiricism in Eastern Philosophy?' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/23510/western-empiricism-in-eastern-philosophy/73463#73463 'How do Chinese and Japanese Buddhists perceive people?' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/81458/how-do-chinese-and-japanese-buddhists-perceive-people/81465#81465 'Philosophers or philosophical traditions that reject symbolic reasoning' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/82360/philosophers-or-philosophical-traditions-that-reject-symbolic-reasoning/82366#82366

Comment: Confucianism was mainly about *social harmony* and Daoism was all about *cosmic harmony*. Buddhism entered the fray, kind courtesy of Bodhidharma et al, and what we get is an amalgam that moved east - Zen Buddhism - which then spread westwards.

Comment: @AgentSmith Kind of, but I feel you have summarized Buddhism too much. Buddhism has *many* different philosophical schools, even at the beginning in India. Zen is not the only form of Buddhism in Japan. The travel to the west was not just Zen coming to the west, IMHO.