# How did the Sophists contribute to modern education?

Tags: education, modernity, sophism

I'm taking a course in Pedagogical Trends and we've studied about Sophists, Socartes and Plato.. So, I want to know how did the Sophists contribute to modern education?

Comment: This is the kind of basic question best addressed by reading general accounts about the sophists, eg https://iep.utm.edu/sophists https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/sophists Do your own homework, & ask a more tightly focused question. I would argue Socrates was paradigmatic in defining philosophy, in part doing so *against* the sophists, & Plato created his Academy, & so academia, by fusing that with Pythagoras' math-mysticism. Discussed here: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/55051/werent-there-any-philosophers-from-africa-america-or-the-middle-east-before-so/82042#82042

Comment: In a sense, modern discussions about [relativism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/relativism/) add nothing to the original Greek Sophists' thesis.