# What does it mean for something to “break” infinite regress?

Tags: epistemology, metaphysics, theology, infinite, foundationalism

When it comes to the cosmological argument, proponents point out that a first cause is needed to stop an infinite regress of causes.

In epistemology, foundationalism is used to break the infinite regress of justification. If every belief needs another to be justified, the process would go on forever, and hence some beliefs don’t need to be justified by others “stopping” the regress.

My question is about how these things are supposed to “stop” the regress and what it actually means. For example, how does a first cause “stop” the regress? If this first cause was always there, isn’t this still creating a regress since there is no “first” moment in time where it existed?

So in essence, what does it mean to “stop” this chain and how does one know that these propositions actually stop them?

Comment: There is a sort of epistemic "optical" illusion, here. Say we have reached a cause that we don't want to go further back from. If we are yet tempted to explain why this cause is the first, rather than some other, we will start regressing at a diagonal to principles of comparison and explanation. Eventually we'll reach another off-kilter edge of ideas, and we'll spiral about; either some angle of the spiral loops back on another, or the regress continues apace; or else we just stop moving, exhausted, wherever we find ourselves standing dizzily for all our spinning.

Comment: In the cosmological argument, causation is not restricted to causation in time. In its sense of "causing", the parallel postulate "causes" (is the reason for) the sum of the angles of a triangle to be two right angles, and time is not involved there at all. “Stopping the regress” is just an idiom too. It simply means that a causal chain must end somewhere  (if one subscribes to foundationalism), and where it ends is the first cause that "stops" or "breaks" the regress.

Comment: @Conifold How does one know that “timeless” causes are possible? I can see justification not depending on time of course since it’s epistemic but don’t seem to understand how one can just assert the concept of a timeless cause without any evidence for it. If one can assert things with no evidence, why not just assert the universe started out of nothing?

Comment: To pre-understand what it even means to break infinite regress for this contingent Saha world if it's possible at all perhaps you should contemplate why propositions in classic logic or its weaker forms such as intuitionistic logic are all timeless, and if you add time for your rumination like in physics, it seems time is constantly flowing in sync with the clock on the wall such that we have idioms like 'time flies so fast', but how fast it really flows? Can you *really* talk about space emerges inside another space or emergent (illusory) time inside another time dimension *ad infinitum*?...

Comment: You misunderstand the terminology. "Causes" are used interchangeably with "reasons" in the cosmological argument (hence "principle of sufficient reason"), and we know plenty of timeless reasons, mathematics is full of them. There is your "evidence". Foundationalists postulate an explanatory reason for the universe, temporal causes do not work as such (regress), "nothing" is not explanatory, timeless reasons are independently available, by IBE, the reason = first cause is timeless. You can protest "explanatory", but many people find the first cause more so than nothing so you are out of luck.

Comment: @Conifold I’m just not sure if that analogy works since mathematics is in the abstract realm and also isn’t a physical entity. Even if we interpret cause as a reason, every physical thing that we **did** found a reason for to exist was just a cause, which involved time. So either way, this seems to be a posit of a process that we don’t even know is possible. Something existing “timelessly” and causing things “timelessly” may be even more implausible than an infinite regress in time.

Comment: Where did you get that every reason in physics was a cause that involved time? Many [explanations in science](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mathematics-explanation/#MathExplEmpiScie) are structural and mathematical, with no time involved. Relativity does not even have time, only spacetime, and its timeless interpretations (eternalism) are popular among physicists. In any case, positing a process we know is not impossible (there are no contradictions) is perfectly fine and routine when it gives a satisfactory explanation of what is observed. Every major new theory does that.

Comment: @Conifold Anything that is physical that has a **known** reason for it to exist involves a cause that preceded that physical thing in time. Can you name me an example otherwise? “Timelessly” causing something that begins to exist is arguably not explanatory. It is just restating the problem. Lastly, given natural language, almost no sentence can be deemed to be “not contradictory” by reinterpretation so that point is moot. Meanings for words change such as the notion for causality always involving time “changing” to include timeless endeavors. Except that this new definition has no basis yet.

Comment: We must do *something*!

Comment: @Conifold I'd separate physical(ish) causes from logical conclusions and structural implications and such. The latter may potentially be a matter of knowledge more than anything else, and doesn't seem capable of giving rise to physical effects. If you have a triangle, you can conclude that the angles sum to 180 degrees, but this doesn't cause that sum or that equality to be created as a physical object (except maybe in some view of Platonism, and existing as a thought). On the other hand, if I were to drop something, there's a physical change in terms of that object falling to the ground.

Comment: You need to read up on relativity and quantum mechanics, you'll have plenty of examples. What you think is or is not explanatory or plausible is beside the point, others have their ideas. Questions about arguments are of interest when asked on their terms, not your personal ones.

Comment: @Conifold Quantum mechanics postulates processes that may be uncaused and arguably exist for no reason as you yourself have alluded to before. This isn’t the same as there existing a reason for a physical thing that did not involve a cause preceding it in time. Lastly, there’s no harm in reading up more things of course, and I can do that. But I don’t think one needs expert opinion to know that “timeless” causes being reasons for physical things are not part of any widespread consensus in physics.

Comment: As your understanding of time apparently did not progress past classical physics, your non-expert opinion is in for a surprise. You do not even need to read experts, pop-sci on relativity will do, look for "block universe" and "eternalism". Compared to "every physical reason that we ever found" even "not part of any widespread consensus" is already progress. Build on it.

Comment: If space or time or spacetime is too abstract and hard for you to contemplate the need to break infinite regress, then perhaps the easiest armchair route is to ruminate why the physical 'real' stuffs we see everyday cannot be composed of infinite layers of 'real' stuffs classically and must encounter quantum which must not be any 'real' stuff? Why light is so important in both relativity's folded light-cone and QM yet is it 'real' if you observe it from light's perspective (meaning you speedup to move along with light to feel like light)? Let there be light and contemplate thus...

Answer (score 0):

The claim of a first cause wouldn't be that it was always there, it would be that at some point there was nothing, and then the first cause made it so that there suddenly started being something. Or perhaps the universe was in some perfectly static state, and then the first cause caused stuff to *start* happening (although then one would also need to posit that the universe was in that initial state).

But if there is nothing (or if things were perfectly static), there would be nothing to be a first cause, so that seems to be a not-insignificant problem.

This leads to some odd ideas, like something causing itself, or something causing an event in the past (that ultimately causes itself). I've heard hypotheses of such things in quantum mechanics, although I'm not too well-versed in that and I don't know how popular such hypotheses are.

Also, with the [spacetime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime) physics model, it's at least theoretically conceivable (if not most likely) that time and how we think of causation (something always having a cause, always being caused by things that happened before it, and only being able to cause things after it) breaks down at the earliest points of the universe. At that point, it may be rather difficult (if not nonsensical) to try to discuss what was "first".

---

The much more common way that a first cause is posited is by calling it ["timeless"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_and_eternity).

In theory, this sidesteps the problem by just asserting that ideas such as "before" and "always" doesn't apply to the cause.

In my view, this assertion is unjustified and contrived in apologetics (it's asserted as a property of God, so God can serve as the only solution to a presented problem, rather than being a conclusion reached based on any sort of evidence or rational justification). It also introduces a far bigger problem of what it even means to be timeless, how something could exist timelessly, and how a timeless entity could have the properties attributed to it (e.g. consciousness).

Yes, I did just allude to how we think of causation breaking down in the section above, which could conceivably allow for the possibility of timelessness. But the breakdown of causation is a counter-intuitive conclusion (not assumption) that would apply to elementary physics particles. If you want the first cause to have consciousness, this introduces additional problem of how it's possible to think without time (given that we tend to consciously think fairly sequentially) and space (given that the only consciousnesses we know of are tied to physical bodies*). Also, if timelessness, and causation from it, is possible in physics, God would not be necessary to terminate the regress, which rather undermines e.g. people trying to prove God's necessity using [the cosmological argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalam_cosmological_argument).

* [Idealism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idealism) posits non-physical consciousness, and that reality is a result of consciousness. This renders the entire discussion of causes within reality somewhat moot. It might solve the first cause of observed reality (that cause then trivially being consciousness), but it mostly just pushes back the problem, and creates a few more, because then the question would become what caused that consciousness, or what was the "first cause" within that consciousness, and where and how does that consciousness exist, and how is that consciousness linked to observed reality, and what explanatory power or justification does the claim of such a consciousness have.

Answer (score 0):

> how does a first cause “stop” the regress? If this first cause was
> always there, isn’t this still creating a regress since there is no
> “first” moment in time where it existed?

I think of it as *short circuiting* the claim of an infinite regress. So, you still go backwards, but you do not go back forever.

> there is no “first” moment in time where it existed

A first cause exists eternally, so you cannot go before him, even conceptually. When you get to god, you "stop", and are no longer thinking of a regress any more, because has doesn't have a cause and/or because you cannot think of anything before him,

You have to take add up all terms CAUSAL INFINITE REGRESS, not just 'causal', 'infinite' and 'regress'.

Comment: The point is that if god is eternal and he exists in time, technically there is an actual infinite regress happening: each moment in time has another moment that precedes it…infinitely. So if an infinite regress exists here, why can’t a regress exist with causality?

Comment: @thinkingman i guess that does kinda make sense... but have you "stopped" the infinite series of *causes*?