# How much knowledge is based in aesthetic virtues like 'elegance'?

Tags: knowledge, aesthetics

How much knowledge is based in aesthetic virtues like 'elegance'? I know that they feature in e.g. inference to the best explanation. What about 'intuition'? When is it ever the deciding factor in what to believe?

Comment: i also have the related question of what the phrase "you should believe" means, but i don't know how best to phrase that question

Answer (score 0):

You might like this answer, which fits aesthetics into a wider picture of [How is Society shaped?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/78998/how-is-society-shaped/79003#79003)

The physicist who developed the theory of the Strong Nuclear Force which governs atomic nuclei said:

> “What is especially striking and remarkable is that in fundamental
> physics a beautiful or elegant theory is more likely to be right than
> a theory that is inelegant.” ― Murray Gell-Mann

It's not the only view though.

> “When asked to judge the promise of a newly invented but untested
> theory, physicist draw on the concepts of naturalness simplicity or
> elegance and beauty. These hidden rules are ubiquitous in the
> foundations of physics. They are invaluable. And in utter conflic with
> the scientific mandate of objectivity.” ― Sabine Hossenfelder, Lost in
> Math: How Beauty Leads Physics Astray

Aesthetics can guide, be a source of heuristics, but not choose for us, I would say.

Comment: so you go with the pretty belief but only *know* when there is evidence etc.? what, if not knowledge, do you call that?